# Storing multiple type of data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a quest system. I have QuestCreator, Quest and multiple objective classes that inherits an interface(TalkObjective, LocationObjective etc.)

In Quest class' constructor, I have created a list like `List<IObjective>`.
It didn't work.

Then I created a class to hold all different types of lists. But I lost the ability of ordering my objectives.

My question is; Is there a better way/design to do that?

[Edit]

I'm sorry that I didn't detailed it enough. Since I changed my code, I can't post it here. I tried to create the same code but this time the code is not giving me error. So I solve the problem on my own.

I was using a tutorial that wasn't completed/abandoned.
[Here is the link to github](https://github.com/HardlyBriefDan/Unity-Make-A-RPG/tree/master/MakeARPG2016/Assets/Quest%20System/Scripts)

I built my Item/Inventory system with abstract classes and it was the first thing that came to my mind. But my intention was to create this quest system the way creator of the tutorial designed, so that I can learn his way.

I wanted to put objects of different Objective Classes in a list with the interface that they using in common way.

```
public class QuestCreator : MonoBehaviour {
#region fields
private List<IQuestObjective> objectives;
private GameObject itemManager;
private ItemDatabase itemdb;
private Location location;
private Quest quest;

//For Saving Quest
private Quest_data quests;
#endregion


void Update()
{
    //Just for the test purpose
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E)) 
    {
        itemManager = GameObject.Find ("GameManager");
        itemdb = itemManager.GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();
        Item item = new Item ();
        Item item2 = new Item ();
        item = itemdb.weapon_database[0];
        item2 = itemdb.weapon_database [1];

        CollectionObjective collectionObjective = new CollectionObjective ("Find", 3, item, "Find this precious item");
        CollectionObjective collectionObjective2 = new CollectionObjective ("Find", 1, item2, "Find Sword of Warrior from Dark Passage");
        LocationObjective locationObjective = new LocationObjective ("Go to Green Valley", "Go to " + location, location, false);
        objectives = new List<IQuestObjective> ();
        objectives.Add(collectionObjective);
        objectives.Add (collectionObjective2);
        objectives.Add (locationObjective);

        QuestText questText = new QuestText ();
        QuestIdentifier questIdentifier = new QuestIdentifier();
        questText.Title = "Finding Sword of Warrior";
        questText.DescriptionSummary = "Summary...";
        questText.Hint = "Hint...";
        questIdentifier.QuestID = 1;
        questIdentifier.SourceID = 1;
        quest = new Quest (questIdentifier, questText, objectives);
        Debug.Log (quest.Objectives[1].Description);
        Debug.Log (quest.Objectives.Count);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show some code, and also, explain what you mean by "not working".

Comment: It sounds like you were heading in the right direction with List<IObjective>. However, as Zohar has said before me, please show your code and tell us any errors that you receive

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into inheritance and polymorphism.

In your case you'd have a IObjective class that contains all the common logic:

```
public abstract IObjective : MonoBehaviour
{
     public abstract void CommonMethod();
     public virtual void OverrideIfNeeded(){}
     public void UseAsIs(){}
}
```

CommonMethod has to be overrriden by subclass. OverrideIfNeeded may be overriden or used as it is. UseAsIs cannot be overriden (it can be hidden though).

Then you have a collection:

```
IEnumerable<IObjective> collection;
```

it contains all kind of different objects that are all IObjective and you can iterate and call all  methods from the IObjective:

```
   foreach(IObjective obj in collection)
   {
        obj.CommonMethod(); 
        obj.UseAsIs();
        ...
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for spending your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

At first to all game programming, I'm highly suggesting going through this web book - http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html (it also offers PDF/book variant for some money). It helps You with some game-pattern examples and You will get an idea how games are made.

Your question is kind of broad and related to each person opinion, which should not be listed as a Q on SO, however:

Logically to me it is like: There is 1 Quest (created by factory `QuestCreator`), which contains `List<Objectives>`.

Objective should be an abstract class, containing some variables and methods (Is objective done? - other things that all `Objectives` have in common).

After that You should inherit smaller objective (like `TalkObjective`, `ItemObjective`) and override inner implementation of the methods -> `IsObjectiveDone`.

On 
To be honest, in game-programming, developers are stepping away to avoid inheritance as much as possible. It is too hard to create inheritance tree and then go through the code. Instead they are trying to rely on pattern like [Component](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html) (same source as above).

Adding some example:

```
public abstract class Objective
{
    public bool IsObjectiveDone { get; private set; }

    public virtual void CheckIfDone();
}

public class ObjectiveGroup
{
    public bool AllObjectivesDone => SubObjectives.All(a => a.IsObjectiveDone);
    public Objective[] SubObjectives { get; private set; }

    public static ObjectiveGroup Create(TypeOfQuest aType, Requirements[] aReq)
    { /* factory implementation */ }
}
```

Once You have the example above, You can define each type of "special" objective:

```
public class ItemObjective : Objective
{
    public Item RequiredItem { get; private set; }

    override public void CheckIfDone()
    {
        this.IsObjectiveDone = Player.GetInstance().Inventory.Contains(RequiredItem);
    }
}
```

Once You will want to start new Quest, You will call the factory, which will create the Quest, containing group of objectives. On each objective You will CheckIfDone everytime user do some action/get new item or so.

```
public class Quest
{
    public ObjectiveGroup { get; private set; }

    public Quest(TypeOfQuest aType, Requirements[] aReq)
    {
        this.ObjectiveGroup = ObjectiveGroup.Create(aType, aReq);
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public List<Quest> Quests = new List<Quest>();
    public List<Item> Inventory = new List<Item>();
}


public void Main(/* ... */)
{
    Player player = new Player();
    player.Quests.Add(new Quest(TypeOfQuest.ItemObtain, new Requirements[] { Item["Sword of Conan"] });

    while(true)
    {
        player.Quests.ObjectiveGroup.ForEach(a => a.SubObjectives.ForEach(b => b.CheckIfDone()));

        foreach(var objGrp in player.Quests.ObjectiveGroup)
            if(objGrp.IsObjectiveDone) Console.WriteLine("Quest completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should review the last paragraph coz it is wrong. Game-programmers are not stepping away from inheritance. Contrary, it solves a lot of issue and would most likely solve the OP issue.

Comment: @Everts , honestly in big solutions and projects, developers are getting away of it. Inheritance is too complex to be handled in games, where you are having over 1000 types (classes) of objects. Instead,applications/games are more data-driven, meaning that You are defining it's behaviour just by numbers/scripts (LUA language) and if You want to modify anything, You don't have to compile App again, instead just change few Data files.

Comment: This is getting off-topic from the OP, you support your idea with LUA which is not usable in Unity(the OP platform) by default (still LUA offers inheritance). It should not be about banning inheritance, it should be about using it properly. The OP will most likely solve his issue with proper usage of OOP, inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: @Everts, I agree on that,, but once You get to OOP, people tend to use inheritance everywhere, which slows everything really hard.& it is really useful to get bigger perspective.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Thank you for spending your precious time.
For the book, I heard it before and the website was in my bookmarks. I'm planning to learn Unreal Engine and c++ in the summer. I might buy it in summer. 
For your example, using abstract classes was first thing that came to my mind and your example increased my knowledge. Thank you putting your time to explain.
By the way creating a generic class might work too.

Comment: @user3630634 Thank You for feedback & I agree. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the code you may have for your problem.

```
public class Program
{
    public struct Location
    {
        // Assumes 2D game location
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }

    public struct Character
    {
        public int GameCharId;
    }

    public class BaseObjective
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Description;
    }

    public class TalkObjective : BaseObjective
    {
        public Character TargetCharacter; 
    }

    public class LocationObjective : BaseObjective
    {
        public Location TargetLocation;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<BaseObjective> currentObjectives = new List<BaseObjective>();

        TalkObjective obj1 = new TalkObjective(){ Title = "Talk to Bob", Description = "Bob has some useful information for you", TargetCharacter = new Character(){GameCharId = 87}};
        LocationObjective obj2 = new LocationObjective(){ Title = "Find the thing", Description = "Bob informed you of a thing, go and find it", TargetLocation = new Location(){ X = 33, Y=172}};


        currentObjectives.Add(obj1);
        currentObjectives.Add(obj2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you spending your precious time for help.

Answer (score 0):

The better design, will be using *Finite Automaton* for this task, not some sort of list of objective. 
So, your quest will be described with graph of predicates (conditions where to move to state or not, event listeners if you want) and states (accompishments in quest). For example, let's imagine hero entered some tavern, then he also enters some different quest lines. One of them describes **town robber** quest:

```
[Start] -(talked with barmen about robber)-> [Kill robber]
[Start] -(talked with robber wife) -> [Ask robber to return items]

//this is made for karma decision between two quest lines, so you are free to chose what to do with poor robber, take robber money or gain karma in town.
[Ask robber to return items] -(talked with barmen about robber)-> [Kill robber]
[Kill robber] -(talked with robber wife) -> [Ask robber to return items]

//barmen quest line
[Kill robber] -(robber killed)-> [Success quest (you can take money as reward)]
[Kill robber] -(robber spared)-> [Fail quest]

//wife quest line
[Ask robber to return items] -(robber convinced)-> [Success quest (you can now sleep with his wife for free)]
[Ask robber to return items] -(robber not convinced)-> [Ask robber to return items]
[Ask robber to return items] -(robber got bored of your questions)-> [Fail quest]
```

As you see this is all described with simple automaton rules and you can make pretty complex quests without much effort. In case of your list of objective you can't possibly branch your quest into different states, so only possible way to complete your quest is to meet ALL actions described one by one, even if it has two possible and successful outcomes.

Predicates in this example can be described as events, and states - as simple numbers or strings.

This is just very slow example of how I see it:

```
    public class QAutomaton
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> _graph = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

        public void AddState(string state)
        {
            _graph.Add(state, new Dictionary<string, string>());
        }

        public void AddCondition(string from, string condition, string to)
        {
            _graph[from].Add(condition, to);
        }

        public string GetNext(string from, string condition)
        {
            var conds = _graph[from];
            string nextState;
            conds.TryGetValue(condition, out nextState);
            return nextState;
        }
    }

    public class Quest
    {
        public string CurrentState = "Start";
        private readonly QAutomaton _automaton;

        public Quest(QAutomaton automaton)
        {
            _automaton = automaton;
        }

        public void FeedEvent(string condition)
        {
            var nextState = _automaton.GetNext(CurrentState, condition);
            if (nextState != null)
            {
                CurrentState = nextState;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var fa = new QAutomaton();
        fa.AddState("Start");
        fa.AddState("Kill robber");
        fa.AddState("Ask robber to return items");

        fa.AddCondition("Start", "talked with barmen about robber", "Kill robber");
        fa.AddCondition("Start", "talked with robber wife", "Ask robber to return items");
        //describe rest here...
        _quest = new Quest(fa);
    }

    public static void OnTalkedWithBarmenAboutRobberEventHandler()
    {
        _quest.FeedEvent("talked with barmen about robber");

        var state = _quest.CurrentState;
        if (state == "Kill robber")
        {
            //locate him on global map or something
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure the OP was after a State-Machine like solution. I think he was more after some beginner issue on how to minimize the amount of code. That does not make your answer wrong, just too far-fetched I would guess. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Well, it is always good to show how things done in this field, than solve particular question and leave him to figure out what his solution not flexible at all and he will be forced to hack it out at some point in time. This is not preference, this is just solution which will decrease code to minimum, cheap in memory/performance, theoreticaly supported (easy optimized by various algorithms) and flexible enough to make very complex quests with different outcomes.

Comment: @eocron Thank you spending your precious time for help. I'll definitely spend some time on that design pattern.